# c++ constructor seems to return pointer to the same object every time

Tags: c++

I have a simple implementation of a Linked list class, which has pointers to Node objects which I have also defined.

The function insertHead creates a new Node and inserts it at the head.
However, whenever I call the function, the constructor seems to return a pointer to the same object every time. (I checked that using GDB)

I am pasting snippets of the code here. Can someone please let me know if something seems off?

```
void LinkedList::insertHead(int val){
  Node temp(val);
   if(head == NULL){
    head = tail = &temp;
  } else {
     temp.setNext(head);
     head = &temp;
  }
}
```

Class definitions:

```
class LinkedList{

  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
...

class Node{

  int val;
  Node *next;
...

Node::Node(int x){
  val = x;
  next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You're saving a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope and becomes invalid at the end of that function. The pointer is a pointer to the stack, so it probably is the same every time. If you need to dynamically allocate objects, use `new` or some sort of unique or shared pointer.

Comment: `temp`, as you correctly named it, has automatic lifetime: you're storing dangling pointers to dead objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cant** assign address of `automatic storage` variable and use it out of the body, becouse it got out of scope (`undefined behaviour`). You need to dynamically allocate space on `heap` for the `node`.

```
Node * temp = new Node(val);
if(head == NULL)
{
    head = tail = temp;
} else {
    temp.setNext(head);
    head = temp;
}
```

**And in destructor free all nodes.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate your nodes on heap rather than stack. (I encourage you to read about those two). Also please use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` if supported ( > c++11)

```
void LinkedList::insertHead(int val){
  Node* temp = new Node(val);
  if(head == nullptr){
    head = tail = temp;
  } else {
     temp->setNext(head);
     head = temp;
  }
}
```

This will also require you clean up the nodes properly using the `delete` to avoid memory leaks which will most probably require adding a custom destructor to your list class, something along those lines:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
  Node* node = head;
  while(node != nullptr) {
    Node* toDel = node;
    node = node->next;
    delete toDel;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt get that `Node temp(val)` will make an auto variable. That's what I was missing.